# changing ownership for /dev/bus/usb/

Tags: sudo, usb-device

I would like to change the permission for usb device as normal user with sudo access. In my sudo added as `user ALL =(root) /bin/chown`
getting the usb details using lsusb

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 03f0:034a Hewlett-Packard Elite Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 03f0:094a Hewlett-Packard Optical Mouse [672662-001]
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
**Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0b95:7720 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772**
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

im trying to change the ownership for this device using sudo

```
 Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0b95:7720 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772
```

sudo chown -R root:qemu /dev/bus/usb/002/008

im getting the error `operation not permitted`

Could you please to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance

Vinoth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For changing device permissions you should use [udev rules](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html). Please check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/255723/how-to-change-the-owner-permission-of-device-files) Q/A for more information

Comment: Thanks for the info, let me try based on the shared document